# javascript shopping cart math loop

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to create a loop to display the shopping cart total on my checkout page. I attempted to create some array variables in the loop to hold my values but console give me a " 
 unexpected [  " error.
* My "i" values attached to "p" & "q" are meant to reference IDs in my shopping cart table for the products displayed.

shopping cart table code:

```
<?php 
$query = "select * from tbl_cart WHERE 
member_id= '$member_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
if (!$result) {
printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
exit();
}
echo "<table id='anyclass'>";
echo "<tr>
         <th style= border-right-style:none; 
id='image1'></th>
         <th style= text-align: center; 
border-left-style:none; 
id='product1'>Product</th>
         <th id='price1'>Price</th>
         <th id='quantity1'>Quantity</th>
         <th id='remove1'>Remove</th>


    </tr>";

$i=1;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  


echo "<tr class= 'trhide'>";

echo          '<td style=border-right-
style:none;><img src="' . $row['image'] 
. '" /></td>';

echo          "<td style=border-left-
style:none; 
id='product'>".$row['product_id']."</td>";

echo "<td style= 'text-align: right;' id= 
'p$i' >".$row['price']."
</td>"; 
echo          "<td id= 'quantity' >". "
<input id= 'q$i' style='border:none' 
type = 'text' class= 'change' value= 
$row[quantity] name= $row[id] data-id= 
$row[id] 
>" . "</td>";

echo          "<td id= 'delete'><span 
class='delete' data-id= $row[id] ><img 
src=delete.svg></span></td>";  

echo          "<td id= 'o$i' >".$row['oz']."
</td>"; 
echo      "</tr>";

  $i++;
}
echo  "<tr>
          <td>Total:</td>
          <td id= 'total'></td>

  </tr>";
echo "</table>";


 ?>

    <script>
var total0=0;
var sum=0;
var i;
for (i = 1; i < 1000; i++) { 
   if(document.getElementById("p"+i)==null){
     var p[i]= 0;
    }

else{varp[i]=parseFloat
(document.getElementById
('p'+i).innerText)*100;}




if(document.getElementById('q'+i)==null){
     var q[i]= 0;
    }
    else{var q[i]= 
document.getElementById('q'+i).value;
    }


    var total[i]= parseInt(p[i]) * 
parseInt(q[i]);

    var sum= sum + total[i];

}

window.alert(sum);

</script>
```

Comment: You can explore `looping`

Comment: Thank you. That did occure to me. I'm just not sure how to go about doing it. Could anyone provide an example with my code?

Comment: *"Could anyone provide an example with my code"* Sounds like *"Will someone write this for me?"* Rather than asking why you are experiencing a current issue and how to resolve it. Also within your `php` `while()` loop you are creating duplicate **ID**'s `quantity` ect.... **ID's** should be unique. As for grouping elements you can use a `class` name for that.

Comment: I'm sorry if that is what it sounds like but I honestly don't know how I would go about doing it. If anyone advise as to how I can break this down into loops it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Rather than using **ID**'s look into using a **Class** name and customs `data-` attributes might also be helpful. I can provide you a simple example but before I do that I need to see you have done some sort of research and made an attempt of your own.

Comment: Thank  you for the edit with the helpful comments. I believe you are mistaken about there being a duplicate "quantity" ID there is a "quantity" and a "quantity1" with control F I did not find any duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is good code but it worked for me and solved my problem.

```
<script>
var total0=0;
var sum=0;
var i;
var q = new Array();
var p = new Array();
var total = new Array();
for (i = 1; i < 1000; i++) { 
   if(document.getElementById("p"+i)==null){
      p[i]= 0;
    }

else{p[i]=parseFloat(document.getElementById('p'+i)
.innerText)*100;
    }

     if(document.getElementById('q'+i)==null){
     q[i]= 0;
    }
    else{q[i]= document.getElementById('q'+i).value;
    }



    total[i]= parseInt(p[i]) * parseInt(q[i]);

    var sum= sum + total[i];

}

var result= sum/100;
document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = '$' + 
result;
```